# Rails Devise: Separate Profile or integrate with Devise Controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, profiles

I have a web app that will have 4 different users on it:

Owner Admin (My Team and I)
Common User of the App (the everyday people using the site
Company Admins (The people who pay the bills)
Company Users

Of these the last 3 will require profiles and other controller and Model relations.

My question is do I create separate controllers for each of these users and have them link through their current devise ID to their individual profile, or should I edit the devise DB tables to accommodate for profiles and different levels of access?

Cheers,

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

Mostly depends on what you want. I prefer to use a single table for all user types.

> should I edit the devise DB tables to accommodate for profiles and different levels of access?

Again depends on what you want since there are many ways to provide different levels of access.

- Edit user table (ie. roll your own solution on top of devise)
- use authorization gem (eg. cancan)

Therefore no hard answers.